# Problem in power up generation

Tags: c#, unity

I am trying to instantiate an obstacles, Currency and Power up in the game. i am using same script to instantiate all. obstacles and currency are working perfectly but power ups is not generating in a game. it displays an error message

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
ElementsGeneratorss.instantiateElement (Int32 elementNumber, Vector3 v3Position, Single CurrentAngle, Vector3 hitInfoNormal) (at Assets/GameKit/C# Scripts/ElementsGeneratorss.cs:312)
ElementsGeneratorss.generateElements (Int32 elementNumber, Single fLocation, Boolean bStartPatch) (at Assets/GameKit/C# Scripts/ElementsGeneratorss.cs:225)
ElementsGeneratorss+c__Iterator1.MoveNext () (at Assets/GameKit/C# Scripts/ElementsGeneratorss.cs:115)

i used C# Script

```
private void instantiateElement(int elementNumber, Vector3 v3Position, float CurrentAngle, Vector3 hitInfoNormal)
{
    if (elementNumber < 0)
        return;

    Transform ObjectHandle;

    if (elementNumber < iObstacleCount)//obstacles
    {
        // for generating obstacles. its working perfectly
    }
    else if (elementNumber >= iObstacleCount && elementNumber < (iObstacleCount+iPowerupCount))//powerups
    {
        ObjectHandle = elements[elementNumber].tPrefabHandle[elements[elementNumber].iPrefabHandleIndex];
        elements[elementNumber].iPrefabHandleIndex++;
        if (elements[elementNumber].iPrefabHandleIndex >= elements[elementNumber].tPrefabHandle.Length)
            elements[elementNumber].iPrefabHandleIndex = 0;
        ObjectHandle.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        ObjectHandle.up = hitInfoNormal;
        ObjectHandle.position = v3Position;
        ObjectHandle.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0,0,0);
        ObjectHandle.Rotate(0,CurrentAngle,0);
        ((PowerupScriptss)ObjectHandle.GetComponent(typeof(PowerupScriptss))).initPowerupScript();
    }
    else if (elementNumber == (iObstacleCount+iPowerupCount))//currency
    {
        // for generating currency. working perfectly
    }
}
```

Comment: Read the error message. It points out where to issue is.

Comment: it displays an error message in "ObjectHandle.gameObject.SetActive(true);'

Comment: After assignment of `ObjectHandle`, check if it is null or not, by logs or breakpoint. And also add `null` check after this line

Comment: no its not null. i used the same method for currency and obstacles. its working. power ups only not working

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Set the currency value to a very low number, e.g. if you set the value to 10 it will generate a large count.

Comment: I'm not sure what this answer is trying to say. I'd recommend editing it to be more descriptive about the solution, with care to spelling & grammar (eg. is "vow" meant to be "low," and "its ll" meant to be "it will"?)